# Reading rows from Java of a table with 3000000 rows

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I want to read the rows of a table with 30000000 rows. I have used `st.setFetchSize(10000)` thinking I will get the 30000000 rows in packages of 10000 but I only get the first 10000 rows and the program ends. Please could anyone tell me how to get all 30000000 rows in packages of 10000?

```
public class InsertBatch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres", "postgres", "root")) {
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            Statement st = connection.createStatement(
                ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY,
                ResultSet.FETCH_FORWARD
            );
            System.out.println(new Date());
            st.setFetchSize(10000);
            System.out.println("start query ");
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM contratacion");
            System.out.println("done query ");
            String insert = "INSERT INTO contrato(contrato, codigo_postal,cups) VALUES(?, ?, ?)\n" +
            "ON CONFLICT (contrato) DO\n" +
            "UPDATE SET codigo_postal = excluded.codigo_postal, cups = excluded.cups";
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(insert);
            int cont = 0;
            while(rs.next()) {
                cont++;
                Integer contrato  = rs.getInt(1);
                Integer codigo_postal  = rs.getInt(2);
                String cups  = rs.getString(3);

                pst.setInt(1, contrato);
                pst.setInt(2, codigo_postal);
                pst.setString(3, cups);
                pst.executeUpdate();
                connection.commit();
                System.out.println(cont);
            }
            System.out.println(new Date());
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would we know what you did wrong to not get all the rows? Perhaps it's because you messed up that line 13 in the code we cannot see.

Comment: Reading thirty million rows from the database is likely *not* the optimal solution to your true problem. [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 3):

Please **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`createStatement​(int resultSetType, int resultSetConcurrency, int resultSetHoldability)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#createStatement(int,int,int)):

> **Parameters:**
>
> `resultSetType` - one of the following `ResultSet` constants: `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`, `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`, or `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`
>
> `resultSetConcurrency` - one of the following `ResultSet` constants: `ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY` or `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE`
>
> `resultSetHoldability` - one of the following `ResultSet` constants: **`ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT` or `ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT`**

Your code is:

```java
Statement st = connection.createStatement(
                  ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, // Good
                  ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY,  // Good
                  ResultSet.FETCH_FORWARD      // BAD !!!!!
               );
```

As you can see, the 3rd parameter is **not** one of the valid values.

Since you call `connection.commit();` inside the `while(rs.next())` loop, it'd work much better for you if you pass **`ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT`**.

---

Of course, you shouldn't even be doing that, because 3000000 `INSERT` statements will take forever, especially if you commit each one individually. *Yikes!*

If you have to, because you need to process the data in Java, at least use *batching*.

Instead, just write it as a single statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO contrato ( contrato, codigo_postal, cups )
SELECT contrato, codigo_postal, cups
FROM contratacion
ON CONFLICT (contrato) DO UPDATE
SET codigo_postal = excluded.codigo_postal
  , cups = excluded.cups
```

Comment: This would also indicate a bug in the driver, as a driver should throw an exception if it gets the wrong value.